# Why am I seeing purple hedges in Sanctuary Hills when adding mods?

Tags: fallout-4

I've been playing fallout 4 with mods. Lately I've been coming across Sanctuary Hills having purple hedges, and some things load in at a certain angle. I've tried removing certain mods affecting Sanctuary. Has anyone experiencing this problem  sorted it out?

Comment: The thing to try is removing ALL mods. Once that's done, see if the problem persists. If not, activate mods a few at a time until you notice the problem returns. You can easily narrow your culprit down this way, and uninstall the offending mod.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf or do the binary method. much faster than doing a few at a time on average

Comment: @Dragonrage You're right, but it's 6 of one half a dozen of another in the end.

Answer (score 6):

### Purple stuff normally means missing textures

In a lot of game engines purple is a kind of null-color. If an image resource can't be located the game will color the object purple in its stead. It could be that some of your mods over-wrote core game assets, and the textures are missing from the game files. If you've uninstalled all mods and still see purple bushes, this could very well be the problem.

If you're playing on PC/Steam, I'd suggest going into your game properties and hitting '**Verify integrity of game cache.**' This will look through your game directory and re-download any missing or corrupted files. Alternatively, you can uninstall/reinstall the game, but you should take care to manually copy your savegames to a backup directory.

### It could be a symptom of something more serious

If the above doesn't work, or you see more strange graphical artifacts, it could be that your GPU is dying. The games assets could be fine, but your GPU is failing to load/calculate things properly. It might struggle on for a while, but eventually it will fail completely. A total GPU failure typically manifests as hundreds of purple dots on screen, rainbow-static on startup, or a complete failure to boot. Unfortunately, the only fix I know of is to buy a new one.

It's worth noting that GPUs can be damaged by being under-powered. If you installed a new GPU in an off-the-shelf PC it's possible that the power supply isn't feeding enough power for it to run properly. If you built your own PC, be doubly sure the power supply is large enough to feed every component of the system.

It's also possible that heat, dust, moisture, or even manufacturing defects are causing your GPU to fail prematurely. Hopefully, this isn't the case, but it's possible.

Comment: #2 is very painful, but yes, it definitely can happen.  However, don't ever jump to the #2 conclusion.  Driver updates, cleaning computer, and re-installs are typical troubleshooting steps to fix the other problems.